# Create one user and role in OnModelCreating for EF core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am working on an asp.net-core 2.0 project.

This project contains a database with Entity Framework Core. I am working on Code First mode with migrations.

What i want to do is to create some default datas in my database on structure creation.

I need to create an User.

I have looked in OnModelCreating function in my IdentityDbContext class but i have no way to access to userManager object.

So i do not know how to do.... Thanks

Here is my code:

```
    public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<Utilisateurs>
    {
        public static string ConnectionString;

        public MyContext()
        {

        }

        public MyContext(DbContextOptions<pluginwebContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(MyContext.ConnectionString);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            var user = new MyUserClass { UserName = "test" };

            // Error There
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(user, "1234");
        }

        public DbSet<MyTable1> table1 { get; set; }
        ...
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

The convention of initializing data in DbInitialize class not in modelCreating method. The mostly used way using modelCreating is that mapping your entities to database tables like following code.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
     modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
     modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
     modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
}
```

Later, you can create a class for your dummy object.

```
  public static class DbInitializer
    {
        public static void Initialize(SchoolContext context)
        {
            //context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            // Look for any students.
            if (context.Students.Any())
                {
                    return;   // DB has been seeded
                }

        var courses = new Course[]
                    {
                        new Course {CourseID = 1050, Title = "Chemistry",      Credits = 3,
                            DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Engineering").DepartmentID
                        },
                        new Course {CourseID = 4022, Title = "Microeconomics", Credits = 3,
                            DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Economics").DepartmentID
                        },
                        new Course {CourseID = 4041, Title = "Macroeconomics", Credits = 3,
                            DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Economics").DepartmentID
                        },
                        new Course {CourseID = 1045, Title = "Calculus",       Credits = 4,
                            DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "Mathematics").DepartmentID
                        },
                        new Course {CourseID = 2042, Title = "Literature",     Credits = 4,
                            DepartmentID = departments.Single( s => s.Name == "English").DepartmentID
                        },
                    };

                    foreach (Course c in courses)
                    {
                        context.Courses.Add(c);
                    }
                    context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Yes but the problem is for user table, i need userManager object

Comment: Can you explaing what you mean userManager Object? Do you mean user crud operations in usermanager class ?

Comment: This is because my user class is derivating from IdentityUser. When i need to create a user, i cannot insert it directly, i need to work with UserManager<> and RoleManager<> classes